# rar - command line switch for exclude compress but store?

Tags: command-line, compression, window, rar, winrar

Assuming I have few files like :

```
--- +Royi
    |
    +---1.txt    
    +---2.txt
    +---3.Avi
    +---4.mp4
    +---5.docx
```

looking at :

`rar a -r -m1 Royi myArchive.rar`

This will shrink all files (*fastest shrink option , before 100% store*)

But `avi` and `mp4` are *already compressed* formats which I don't want to spend time again on compressing with `rar` — I would like to store them ( 100% append) so it won't spend time trying to compress them

But I want this to be done only on certain files.

**Question:**

Is there any switch which does the following (psuedo) :

`rar a -r -m1 Royi myArchive.rar -NoCompress(*.avi,*.mp4)`

NB I know I can create separate rar files. But I don't want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `rar`'s help screen:

> ms[ext;ext]   Specify file types to store

You can use it like so:

```
rar a -r -m1 -msavi;mp4 myArchive.rar Royi
```